# Is the set of all the subsets of a completely separable space still completely separable?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, separable-spaces

Let $T$ be a completely separable topological space, is $2^T$ still completely separable? I seriously doubt that the subset of $2^T$ cannot be written as the countable union of the basis open sets of $2^T$.

---

Second question: Let $X$ be a connected separable topological space, is $2^X$ still connected separable? How to prove this?

Not a homework.

Comment: $2^X$ is the Vietoris hyperspace of $X$? I.e. all non-empty closed sets and using the Vietoris subbase $\{[U], \langle  U \rangle : U \in \mathcal{T}\}$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry, I just started learning the Vietoris topology by reading some notes and some of your answers. Does the Vietoris $H(X)$ usually assume stronger or weaker separation axioms？

Comment: $H(X)$ is only normal if $X$ is compact Hausdorff and then $H(X)$ is too. Higher separation axioms are rarer for $H(X)$. I think only compact metric $X$ (where $H(X)$ is also compact metric) will be completely or perfectly normal.

Comment: @HighGPA I have never heard the term "completely separable".  What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Vietoris topology on the hyperspace is meant: No for completely separable (a.k.a second countable, $C_2$ or $w(X) = \aleph_0$) as the hyperspace of a countable discrete space is regular, but not normal (and so cannot be second countable as a regular second countable space is normal).

$X$ connected and $T_1$ implies $2^X$ connected (classical, not too hard), and $X$ separable and $T_1$ implies that $2^X$ is separable (the finite subsets of the dense subsets are dense). So yes for $T_1$ spaces (which is often assumed in this hyperspace context to ensure that there are enough closed sets and so that $X$ embeds into $2^X$ naturally via $x \to \{x\}$).